# Breadcrumbs not showing category on product page

Tags: magento2

I do have a question regarding breadcrumbs in Magento 2.3.5.

I do have some categories which are not shown in the menu. Meaning I disabled them for the category menu. This is necessary in my layout because of not enough place to display.
I do access these categories with other links.
So far so good, but in this case breadcrumbs are only showing the productname on the product page and not the category names.

Does somebody have an idea how to change this?

Comment: Is this the case that when you open product from home page then breadcrumb is showing "Home -> Product Name"? or you is it something else?

Comment: I first show the category page https://domain/category1.  Breadcrumb shows Home-Category1. But if than l am clicking on product it shows Home-Product. If I configure the category as "showing in menu" breadcrumb is Home-Category1-Product